# Rails : How to store mailer password safely?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I have my rails app on heroku and github and am currently using a mailer in my app:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :user_name            => "myemail@gmail.com",
  :password             => "PasswordShouldGoHere",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

I don't want my email and password to be visible on my github account, since people can just log in and steal my info. However, if I put a fake password, then my app will give me an error on heroku when the mailer is supposed to deliver. I know I can just push up the real email and password to heroku first and then edit it and put the fake password on my github account, but is there a better way?

Comment: I've read about that. Can you tell me how/where exactly environment variables are set?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Like other people said, you can achieve this security by using `ENV` variables. Here's how to do it:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  user_name: ENV["MAILER_EMAIL"],
  password: ENV["MAILER_PASSWORD"]
}
```

Now, in **production** (Heroku), all you have to do is [follow this guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application). It basically amounts to opening your console and typing this:

```
heroku config:set MAILER_EMAIL=email@example.com MAILER_PASSWORD=password
```

In **development**, you can create a file inside the config/initializers folder with a suggestive name like `app_env_vars.rb`. Inside it, place the following:

```
ENV['MAILER_EMAIL'] = 'email@example.com'
ENV['MAILER_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
```

To prevent this newly created file from being pushed into your source control, you should add it to your `.gitignore`:

```
/config/initializers/app_env_vars.rb
```

However, there's a problem because initializer files are only loaded after the environment, so there's one last thing to do. Go to your `environment.rb` file and add the following **before** the `Yourapp::Application.initialize!`:

```
# Load the app's custom environment variables here, before environments/*.rb
app_env_vars = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'initializers', 'app_env_vars.rb')
load(app_env_vars) if File.exists?(app_env_vars)
```

You're done!

However, if you find all of this configuration a hassle, then I recommend using the [Figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro). It does everything I described and more!

Comment: I'm having this problem. Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in Devise::PasswordsController#create

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using [figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) to manage configuration settings. It uses `ENV` to store settings and it's exactly how apps on Heroku are configured.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Rails Apps Tutorial](http://railsapps.github.com/tutorial-rails-devise-rspec-cucumber.html).

The section "Use a Gmail account" shows this example config:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: "example.com",
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
  password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
}
```

and suggests setting the variables in `~/.bashrc` on your server:

```
export GMAIL_USERNAME="myname@gmail.com"
export GMAIL_PASSWORD="secret*"
```

You may need to set them somewhere else if the app server doesn't read the environment from `~/.bashrc`. This is very dependent on what your app server is.