# Rails sign in facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, omniauth

I use omniauth-facebook gem. Generally I'm completely following railscast episode #360 (http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication?autoplay=true)
So I did all like in tutorial.

After creating app on facebook, I set it URL a `http://localhost:3000/`, enabled sandbox mode.

As Ryan says, after creating omniauth.rb, `http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook` should redirect me to my FB app page.

But nothing happens. No errors, just empty page.

I'm really sure, that did everything like in tutorial, and have no idea, what the trouble is

**UPD:** now it shows error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Missing client_id parameter.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 101
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you provided your APP id and key to the script?

Comment: yeah, priblem solved by removing ENV with brackets, although it was in railscast tutorial

Comment: It's a question of security. If you host your application on github or any other public site, you should **not** reveal your APP_KEY and APP_SECRET. That's why you should use ENV variables to keep them safe. See **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294194/rails-how-to-store-mailer-password-safely/13296207#13296207)** on how you can achieve this.