# rails environment variables from environment.rb in omniauth initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

I am unable to read the variables I defined in environment.rb file for omniauth.

This is my code:

## environment.rb

```
ENV['LINKEDIN_KEY'] = "key"
ENV['LINKEDIN_SECRET'] = "secret"
```

## omniauth.rb initializer

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :linkedin, ENV['linkedin_key'], ENV['linkedin_secret']
end
```

This only works for me if I hard code the key and secret.
I am using Rails 4 and Ruby 2.

In the main example of omniauth they used it the same way:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :developer unless Rails.env.production?
  provider :twitter, ENV['TWITTER_KEY'], ENV['TWITTER_SECRET']
end
```

I would love some help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean environment?

Comment: The point of using `ENV` variables is so that you can keep them out of source control like git. Adding `ENV` variables to the `environment.rb` file (which is usually commmited) is exactly the same as hard-coding the variables. Please check this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294194/rails-how-to-store-mailer-password-safely/13296207

Comment: This is just to get started. this is not on git yet. it will later be moved of course.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that the case is an issue in your middleware:

```
provider :linkedin, ENV['linkedin_key'], ENV['linkedin_secret']
```

In your environment.rb you are using upper case:

```
ENV['LINKEDIN_KEY'] = "key"
ENV['LINKEDIN_SECRET'] = "secret"
```

I also recommend you have a look at [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) to manage you environment data - it keeps sensitive information from your source control.

Comment: you are right about the upper and lower. but that's after a long time playing with it. its not the problem. as I see it now omniauth changed the builder in 1.0 and now they offer a new way to load: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Dynamic-Providers

Comment: I have this in my initializer for github

    Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
      provider :github, ENV["GITHUB_ID"], ENV["GITHUB_SECRET"]
    end

Answer (score 2):

After searching for the new dynamic-providers strategy omniauth suggest using I found this page:
https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Setup-Phase

so changed my code to:

```
SETUP_PROC = lambda do |env|
  env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:consumer_key] = ENV['LINKEDIN_KEY']
  env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:consumer_secret] = ENV['LINKEDIN_SECRET']
end

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :linkedin, setup: SETUP_PROC
end
```

And it works!